# multiselect dropdown with search bar and check all or un check all

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

[image]

my issue is that i want to fix the top search bar and select all in multi select drop down so so that when i scroll down agent list its always on the top .
but i fixed its position its over the records behind the search bar and select all

like this given below
[image]

Comment: This question is incomprehensible.

Comment: You need to remove the dropdown from the table and put it in its own row and fix the position of that row.